# DataTable Responsive deletes columns with Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, datatables, bootstrap-5

I want to make a table responsive with `DataTable 1.13.4` and `Bootstrap 5.2.3` but when I test my table on mobile device (with Firefox, not on a real device) my table contains a small horizontal scrollbar but removes columns.

Like explained in the official documentation of DataTable, I have install two depedencies with Yarn :

- `datatables.net-bs5` (DataTable for Bootstrap 5)
- `datatables.net-responsive-bs5` (Plugin to enable responsive for Bootstrap 5)

I know I need to add the Bootstrap 5 `table-responsive` class before declaring my table, but I want to fixed the pagination and the filter, so I've built the `dom` option into my JavaScript when I instantiate the DataTable object (`dom: 'f<"table-responsive"t>...`)

[Click here to see the result on desktop screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYZ4E.png)
[Click here to see the result on mobile screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tI8W.png)

The horizontal scroll bar is not visible on screenshots, but is present on desktop and mobile screen. It's just very small (like 5/10 pixels) and doesn't allow to see the `Description` column on mobile screen which is present in the desktop screen.

My JavaScript file :

```js
import {Controller} from '@hotwired/stimulus';

import DataTable from "datatables.net-bs5";
import "datatables.net-responsive-bs5";

export default class extends Controller {
    connect() {
        new DataTable('#tableMenu', {
            pageLength: 5,
            responsive: true,
            dom: 'f<"table-responsive"t><"row"<"col-sm-12 col-lg-6 mb-3 mb-lg-0"i><"col-sm-12 col-lg-6 d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-end"p>>'
        });
    }
}
```

My HTML file :

```html
<table id="tableMenu" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Titre</th>
        <th>Prix</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for menu in menus %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ path('app.admin.menu.edit', {'id': menu.id}) }}" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="fa fa-pen" style="font-size: 10px;"></i>
                </a>
                <button type="button"
                        id="delete-menu"
                        data-delete-url="{{ path('api.menu.delete', {'id': menu.id}) }}"
                        class="btn btn-danger">
                    <i class="fa fa-xmark" style="font-size: 10px;"></i>
                </button>
            </td>
            <td>{{ menu.title }}</td>
            <td>{{ menu.price / 100 }}€</td>
            <td>{{ menu.description }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Titre</th>
        <th>Prix</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Thanks to all for your help !

Answer (score 1):

After many research, I have found a solution.

I have keep the same code like the original issue but juste added two classes on my `<tr>` attribute :

- `overflow-hidden`
- `text-nowrap`

So, my JavaScript file doesn't has any changes
And my HTML file looks like this :

```html
<table id="tableMenu" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Titre</th>
        <th>Prix</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for menu in menus %}
        <tr class="overflow-hidden text-nowrap">
            <td>
                <a href="{{ path('app.admin.menu.edit', {'id': menu.id}) }}" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="fa fa-pen" style="font-size: 10px;"></i>
                </a>
                <button type="button"
                        id="delete-menu"
                        data-delete-url="{{ path('api.menu.delete', {'id': menu.id}) }}"
                        class="btn btn-danger">
                    <i class="fa fa-xmark" style="font-size: 10px;"></i>
                </button>
            </td>
            <td>{{ menu.title }}</td>
            <td>{{ menu.price / 100 }}€</td>
            <td>{{ menu.description }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Titre</th>
        <th>Prix</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```